# On Euler's elliptic curve for $A^4+B^4 = C^4+D^4$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

To solve,

$$A^4+B^4 = C^4+D^4$$

we use Euler's method. Let,

$$(p+q)^4+(r-s)^4=(p-q)^4+(r+s)^4$$

and define $p = (a^3 - b),\, q = a y,\, r = b  (a^3 - b),\, s = y.\,$ The equation above transforms to the simple form,

$$(a^3 - b) (b^3 - a) = y^2$$

---

**I. Rational points**

This is birationally equivalent to an *elliptic curve*. Assume the case $a=n.$ <strike>*Six*</strike> *Seven* "smallish" solutions are known (with $b_6$ and $b_7$ found by Seiji Tomita in this related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4781142/4781)):

$b_1 =\frac{n\,(\color{red}{1})}{(1)}$

$b_2 =\frac{n\,(\color{red}{4} + n^2 + 10n^4 + n^6)}{(1 + 10n^2 + n^4 + 4n^6)}$

$b_3 =\frac{n\,(\color{red}{9} - 44n^2 + 190n^4 + 100n^6 + n^8)}{(1 + 100n^2 + 190n^4 - 44n^6 + 9n^8)}$

$b_4 =\frac{n\,(\color{red}{16} - 543n^2 + 4632n^4 + 15100n^6 + 10632n^8 + 22758n^{10} + 6568n^{12} + 5820n^{14} + 552n^{16} + n^{18})}{(1 + 552n^2 + 5820n^4 + 6568n^6 + 22758n^8 + 10632n^{10} + 15100n^{12} + 4632n^{14} - 543n^{16} + 16n^{18})}$

$b_5 =\frac{n\,(\color{red}{25} -3524n^2 + 113482n^4 + 979388n^6 +\,\dots\, + 45836n^{18} + 69418n^{20} +2092n^{22} + n^{24})}{(1 + 2092n^2 + 69418n^4 + 45836n^6 +\,\dots\, + 979388n^{18} + 113482n^{20} - 3524n^{22} + 25n^{24})}$

$b_6 = \frac{n(n^{38}+6234n^{36}+569433n^{34}-1574764n^{32}+\,\dots\,+32622105n^6+1538106n^4-15551n^2+\color{red}{36})}{(36n^{38}-15551n^{36}+1538106n^{34}+32622105n^{32}+\,\dots\,-1574764n^6+569433n^4+6234n^2+1)}$

$b_7 = \frac{n(n^{48}+15704n^{46}+3430692n^{44}-57632376n^{42}+\,\dots\,+603165288n^6+13866564n^4-54088n^2+\color{red}{49})}{(49n^{48}-54088n^{46}+13866564n^{44}+603165288n^{42}+\,\dots\,-57632376n^6+3430692n^4+15704n^2+1)}$

$b_8 = \;?$

A curious feature is the coefficients of the numerator and denominator are palindromic wrt to each other.

---

**II. Identities**

These points yield nice identities (after a change of variables) of symmetric form,

$$f(\alpha, \beta)^4 + f(\beta, -\alpha)^4 = f(\alpha, -\beta)^4 + f(\beta, \alpha)^4$$

with the smallest non-trivial $f(\alpha, \beta)$ being of degree $7$.

---

**III. Updates**

*Update 1.* As pointed out by Sidharth Ghoshal (when only six $b_m$ were known):

1. The coefficients of $b_m$ sum to $2^k$, namely $2^0,\,2^4,\,2^8,\,2^{16},\,2^{24},\,2^{36}.$ (*Why?*)
2. The degree $d$ of the denominators are $0, 6, 8, 18, 24, 38$.
3. He pointed out that it seems both the power $k$ and degree $d$ are functions of $m$.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
m&m^2&k&d\\
\hline\color{blue}
1&1&0&0\\
\hline
2&4&4&6\\
\hline\color{blue}
3&9&8&8\\
\hline
4&16&16&18\\
\hline\color{blue}
5&25&24&24\\
\hline
6&36&36&38\\
\hline\color{blue}
7&49&48&48\\
\hline
8&64&64&66\\
\hline\color{blue}
9&81&80&80\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

At the suggestion of Deyi Chen, the expression for $b_1$ has been made consistent with other $b_m$ for odd $m.\,$ <strike>Hopefully someone can find $b_8$ so we can complete this table.</strike> (*Completed.*)

*Update 2.* Thanks to prompt help from Seiji Tomita, we managed to find $b_8$. So what I labelled as $b_9$ earlier was indeed the case. Both fit the patterns above.

$b_8 = \frac{n(\color{red}{64} - 158335n^{2} + 91670880n^{4} + 7908319600n^{6} +  \,\dots\,- 802597088n^{60} + 16598640n^{62} + 34976n^{64} + n^{66})}{(1 + 34976n^{2} + 16598640n^{4} - 802597088n^{6} + \,\dots\, + 7908319600n^{60} + 91670880n^{62} - 158335n^{64} + 64n^{66})}$

$b_9 = \frac{n(\color{red}{81} - 407672n^{2} + 482840284n^{4} + 77282464024n^{6} + \,\dots\, - 7601467144n^{74} + 67097980n^{76} + 70888n^{78} + n^{80})}{(1 + 70888n^{2} + 67097980n^{4} - 7601467144n^{6} +  \,\dots\, + 77282464024n^{74} + 482840284n^{76} - 
 407672n^{78} + 81n^{80})}$

---

**IV. Questions**

1. Tomita and I found these $b_m$ using different techniques. For any given positive integer $m$, is it always possible to find a rational polynomial $b_m$ that fit the patterns in the table above, such as the palindromicity and numerator having a linear term that is $m^2$?
2. And how do we explain Ghoshal's observation that the coefficients sum to $2^{ 4\left\lfloor \frac{m^2}{4} \right\rfloor }$?

**P.S.** A related question was asked in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779869/finding-rational-points-on-the-elliptic-curve-for-a4b4-c4d4) but focuses on other aspects.

Comment: Are there any combinatorial identities with those coefficients? I can’t seem to find say all the $n^2$ numerator coefficients on OEIS

Comment: It looks like after the checking just the first 4, the sum of coefficients is always a power of a power of 2. $2=2^1,16=2^{2^2},256 = 2^{2^3},65536 = 2^{2^4}$ there might be other combinatorial identities hidden around with these coefficients…

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal That's a very interesting observation. Didn't notice that. The complete sequence for the six is $2^1,\, 2^4,\, 2^8,\, 2^{16},\, 2^{24},\, 2^{36}.$ The exponents are neither in the OEIS. I guess the fact that the coefficients sum to $2^k$ should be a test for $b_7$.

Comment: On the even cases the coefficient the polynomial is always 2 greater than the power of 2. So $2^4$ has a $n^6$ and $2^{16}$ has an $n^{18}$ and $2^{36}$ has an $n^{38}$ based on this we can guess that for $b_7$ the power of 2 exponent and polynomial exponent should agree.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Tomita just found $b_7$ and you're right, the exponent $k$ of $2^k$ and the degree $d$ of denominator does agree as $d=k=7^2-1=48$. Same thing with my $b_9$ as $d=k=9^2-1=80$. I made a table in the post.

Comment: The ratios of the exponents in the consecutive powers of 2  (which you call $k$) are $\frac{2}{1},\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{3}$ while we don’t know $b_8$ if we continue this pattern we find $\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{4}$ and so this suggests $k(b_9)/k(b_7) = \frac{5}{3}$ it’s easy to verify $\frac{80}{48} = \frac{5}{3}$ so this is likely a pattern here as well

Comment: Based on this we guess $k(b_8) = 64$ and most likely $d(b_8) = 66$

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: Tomita and I just found $b_8$. I've updated the table and  $b_8$'s properties is consistent with your guess. Nice, isn't it? The question then is to explain these properties.

Comment: Wow that’s really lucky for us! The k values then are probably just 4 times this value: https://oeis.org/A002620 also I didn’t get a chance to mention this earlier but the coefficients of the $n^2$ term in the numerator track values $r_n^2 \mod 3$ where $r_n$ takes on a sequence of consecutive integer. I suspect it might be useful to look at individual coefficients of a fixed power modulo various numbers as well as look at the polynomials themselves modulo various polynomials to try to find some patterns

Comment: i made an edit to your question, feel free to change it/roll it back if you feel its inappropriate

Comment: Okay so another observation these magic polynomials in the numerator are equivalent to $1, 1, n^2 \mod 3$ in what appears to be a repeating pattern. This might be a very stupid/naive approach but we could just keep on trying to find such patterns modulo as many polynomials as possible and then try to use the chinese remainder theorem to predict what $b_{10}$ ought to be (or we collect more data and then try to do it on say $b_{30}$ or something to that effect)

Comment: The values of $\left|\frac{b_{k+1}(i)}{b_k(i)}\right|$  are so far all powers of 12, the sequence starting from $b_2$ looks like $12,144,144, 1728, 1728, 20736, 20736$ ... I suspect that if the naive pattern repeats then $|b_{10}(i)/b_9(i)| = 248832$

Comment: $k(m)=(-2 + (-1)^m + (-1)^{2 m} + 2 m^2)/2$ and $d(m)=(3 (-1)^m + (-1)^{2 m} + 2 m^2)/2$ for $m$=`2..9`. $k(10)\overset{?}{=}100$ and $d(10)\overset{?}{=}102$.

Comment: Let $l(m)$ number of monomial in denominators, then $l(m)=(4 + 3 (-1)^m + (-1)^{2 m} + 2 m^2)/4$ for $m$=`2..9`. $l(10)\overset{?}{=}52$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Thanks! The sequence from $m=1-10$ is $l(m) = 1, 4, 5, 10, 13, 20, 25, 34, 41, 52.$ However, yesterday I considered the table makes more sense as odd and even $m$. Thus, for odd m we have $l(2n-1) = 2(n^2-n)+1 =  1, 5, 13, 25, 41$ and even m as $l(2n) = 2(n^2+1) = 4, 10, 20, 34, 52$. Do know if we can use the group law of elliptic curves to generate $b_{10}$ explicitly?

Comment: I added an answer, that i considered to be a full answer when i started to type... It addresses the property asked initially about the red square free coefficients in the writing of $b_k(n)/n$ as monic polynomial in $n$ divided by the polynoial with coefficients in reversed order. I between, there are further questions and observations. If some of them are of higher interest, please drop a note to my answer...

Comment: ... and now there are some further details for the computations of $b_k(1)$. The answer comes with a proof for the fact that $b_k(1)$ is two to the power $k^2-1$ or $k^2$ or $k^2+1$, the key for the repeating pattern is explained. More details can be given only in an experimental paper. I may find the time to drop one on the net... Some words on other evaluations in the primitive unit roots $i$ of order $4$ and $u$ of order $8$ were added, as the place allowed it. I had to shorten a lot to get below 30T characters in the edited answer.

Comment: @dan_fulea Thanks, dan. I’ll ask another question soon in MSE which should give a fuller picture. This 3rd family yields identities of deg $k =4m+11$, unlike the first which yields deg $k=6m+7$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is a partial answer.**
Using the group law of elliptic curves, we have,

$b_{10}=\frac{\left(n^{102}+133370 n^{100}+235431945 n^{98}-53960558412 n^{96}+\,\dots\,+607383986505 n^{6}+2125016730 n^{4}-948799 n^{2}+100\right) n}{100 n^{102}-948799 n^{100}+2125016730 n^{98}+607383986505 n^{96}+\,\dots\,-53960558412 n^{6}+235431945 n^{4}+133370 n^{2}+1}$

All other $b_{m}$ can also be generated. Given,

$$(a^3-b)(b^3-a) = y^2$$

---

**I. First family ($a=n$)**

Denote $$E_1=\{(U,V): V^2 = -U^4+n^3U^3+nU-n^4\}\cup O.$$
It is birationally equivalent to Weierstrass form
$$E_2=\{(X,Y): Y^{2}+\left(3 n^{2}-1\right)XY + \left(2 n^{6}-10 n^{4}+8 n^{2}\right)Y
 = 
X^{3}+\left(\frac{3}{4} n^{4}-\frac{9}{2} n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right) X^{2}+4 n^{2} \left(n -1\right)^{2} \left(n +1\right)^{2} X +3 n^{10}-24 n^{8}+38 n^{6}-16 n^{4}-n^{2}
\}\cup O$$
by,
$$\small{U = 
\frac{-3 n^{7}+21 n^{5}+\left(-4 X -17\right) n^{3}+\left(4 X +2 Y -1\right) n}{2 Y}\\
V = 
-\frac{\left(n +1\right) n \left(-3 n^{10}+\left(\frac{9 X}{8}+24\right) n^{8}+\left(-\frac{35 X}{2}+\frac{Y}{4}-38\right) n^{6}+\left(\frac{9}{4} X^{2}+\frac{191}{4} X -\frac{17}{4} Y +16\right) n^{4}+\left(-\frac{27}{2} X^{2}+\frac{1}{2} X -\frac{17}{4} Y +1\right) n^{2}+X^{3}-\frac{3 X^{2}}{4}+\frac{X}{8}+\frac{Y}{4}\right) \left(n -1\right)}{Y^{2}}\\
X =
\frac{n \left(3 U \,n^{4}-n^{5}-4 U \,n^{2}-2 V \,n^{2}+U +2 V +n \right)}{\left(U -n \right)^{2}}\\
Y = 
-\frac{3n \left(n +1\right) \left(n -1\right)} {2 \left(U -n \right)^{3}}  \left(-\frac{n^{6}}{3}+2 U \,n^{5}+\left(U^{2}-6\right) n^{4}+\frac{4 \left(5 U -2 V \right) n^{3}}{3}+\left(-6 U^{2}+1\right) n^{2}+2 \left(U +\frac{4 V}{3}\right) n -\frac{U^{2}}{3}\right)}$$

Let
$P=\left(3 n^{2}+1, -2 n^{6}-\frac{1}{2} n^{4}-5 n^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\in E_2,$
then the $U$ corresponding to $[m-1]P$ is exactly $b_m$ where $m\geq 1$.

---

**II. Second family ($a=n^3$)**

Denote $$E_3=\{(U,V):V^{2} = n^{9} U^{3}-n^{12}-U^{4}+n^{3} U\}\cup O.$$
It is birationally equivalent to
$$E_4=\{(X,Y):Y^{2} = 
X^{3}+\left(3 n^{10}-6 n^{2}\right) X^{2}+\left(3 n^{20}-15 n^{12}+12 n^{4}\right) X -9 n^{22}+18 n^{14}-9 n^{6}
\}\cup O$$
by $$\small{\left[U = \frac{n \left(3 n^{10}-3 n^{2}+X \right)}{X},\, V = 
\frac{3 Y \,n^{11}-3 Y \,n^{3}}{X^{2}},\, X = 
\frac{3 n^{11}-3 n^{3}}{U -n},\, Y = 
\frac{3 V \,n^{11}-3 V \,n^{3}}{\left(U -n \right)^{2}}\right]}
$$
Let $Q=(n^{12}-n^{10}+n^{6}+2 n^{2}+1, n^{18}+n^{12}+n^{6}+1) \in E_4,$ then the $U$ corresponding to $[m]Q$ is exactly $b_m$ where $m\geq 1$. For example,

$b_1=\frac{\left(n^{6}+n^{4}-2 n^{2}+1\right) n}{n^{6}-2 n^{4}+n^{2}+1}$

$b_2=\frac{n \left(n^{12}+8 n^{10}+10 n^{6}-4 n^{2}+1\right)}{n^{12}-4 n^{10}+10 n^{6}+8 n^{2}+1}$

$b_3=\frac{\left(n^{30}+17 n^{28}-18 n^{26}+101 n^{24}-172 n^{22}+80 n^{20}+282 n^{18}-82 n^{16}-244 n^{14}+282 n^{12}-28 n^{10}-64 n^{8}+101 n^{6}+9 n^{4}-10 n^{2}+1\right) n}{n^{30}-10 n^{28}+9 n^{26}+101 n^{24}-64 n^{22}-28 n^{20}+282 n^{18}-244 n^{16}-82 n^{14}+282 n^{12}+80 n^{10}-172 n^{8}+101 n^{6}-18 n^{4}+17 n^{2}+1}
$

$b_4=\frac{n \left(n^{48}+32 n^{46}+552 n^{42}-1088 n^{40}-16 n^{38}+5820 n^{36}+8160 n^{34}+544 n^{32}+6552 n^{30}+18560 n^{28}-4080 n^{26}+23302 n^{24}+8160 n^{22}-9280 n^{20}+6552 n^{18}-1088 n^{16}-4080 n^{14}+5820 n^{12}+32 n^{10}+544 n^{8}+552 n^{6}-16 n^{2}+1\right)}{n^{48}-16 n^{46}+552 n^{42}+544 n^{40}+32 n^{38}+5820 n^{36}-4080 n^{34}-1088 n^{32}+6552 n^{30}-9280 n^{28}+8160 n^{26}+23302 n^{24}-4080 n^{22}+18560 n^{20}+6552 n^{18}+544 n^{16}+8160 n^{14}+5820 n^{12}-16 n^{10}-1088 n^{8}+552 n^{6}+32 n^{2}+1}
$

$b_5=\frac{n \left(n^{78}+49 n^{76}-50 n^{74}+2093 n^{72}-9092 n^{70}+7024 n^{68}+71486 n^{66}+146362 n^{64}-221372 n^{62}+120846 n^{60}+1989884 n^{58}-1997248 n^{56}+2411691 n^{54}+2513095 n^{52}-3945398 n^{50}+4925063 n^{48}+1374136 n^{46}-4812512 n^{44}+9246036 n^{42}+3689036 n^{40}-10556008 n^{38}+9246036 n^{36}+2487832 n^{34}-5926208 n^{32}+4925063 n^{30}+3430735 n^{28}-4863038 n^{26}+2411691 n^{24}+1056332 n^{22}-1063696 n^{20}+120846 n^{18}+102298 n^{16}-177308 n^{14}+71486 n^{12}-3476 n^{10}+1408 n^{8}+2093 n^{6}+25 n^{4}-26 n^{2}+1\right)}{n^{78}-26 n^{76}+25 n^{74}+2093 n^{72}+1408 n^{70}-3476 n^{68}+71486 n^{66}-177308 n^{64}+102298 n^{62}+120846 n^{60}-1063696 n^{58}+1056332 n^{56}+2411691 n^{54}-4863038 n^{52}+3430735 n^{50}+4925063 n^{48}-5926208 n^{46}+2487832 n^{44}+9246036 n^{42}-10556008 n^{40}+3689036 n^{38}+9246036 n^{36}-4812512 n^{34}+1374136 n^{32}+4925063 n^{30}-3945398 n^{28}+2513095 n^{26}+2411691 n^{24}-1997248 n^{22}+1989884 n^{20}+120846 n^{18}-221372 n^{16}+146362 n^{14}+71486 n^{12}+7024 n^{10}-9092 n^{8}+2093 n^{6}-50 n^{4}+49 n^{2}+1}
$

and so on.

---

**Note 1:**
In the first family, I think it is nice to denote $b_1=\frac{n\times \color{red}{1}}{1}.$

For the first family, the sum of the coefficients of $b_m$'s denominator is $2^{k(m)}$ where $k(m)=0, 4, 8, 16, 24, 36, 48, 64, 80, 100, 120, 144, 168, 196, 224, 256.$ (See https://oeis.org/A137932).

For the second family, the sum of the coefficients of $b_m$'s denominator is $2^{k(m)}$ where $k(m)=0, 4, 8, 16, 24, 36, 48, 64, 80, 100, 120, 144, 168, 196, 224.$ (See https://oeis.org/A137932).

That is  $k(m)= 2 {\lfloor \frac{m^{2}}{2}\rfloor}.$

I have verified the first for $1\leq m \leq 16 $ and the second for $1\leq m \leq 15. $

---

**Note 2:**

For the first family, the degree of $b_m$'s denominator is $d(m)=2\alpha(m)$ where
$\alpha(m)=0, 3, 4, 9, 12, 19, 24, 33, 40, 51, 60, 73, 84, 99, 112.$ (See https://oeis.org/A097063).

For the second family, the degree of $b_m$'s denominator is $d(m)=6\beta(m)$ where
$\beta(m)=1, 2, 5, 8, 13, 18, 25, 32, 41, 50, 61, 72, 85, 98, 113.$ (See https://oeis.org/A000982).

It is worth noting,

$$\alpha(m)-\beta(m)=(-1)^m$$

I have verified this for $1\leq m \leq 15 $. I think it is true for all $m\geq 1$.

---

**Note 3: identities**

The discriminant of $E_2$ is
$$\Delta=-432 n^{20}+864 n^{12}-432 n^{4} = 
-432 n^{4} \left(n -1\right)^{2} \left(n +1\right)^{2} \left(n^{2}+1\right)^{2} \left(n^{4}+1\right)^{2}
.$$
Let $\Delta=0$, we have
$$n=0,\pm1,\pm I,\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+I),\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-I)$$
where $I^2=-1.$ Some identities are related to these values.

In the following we denote $b_m(n)=n\frac{P_m(n)}{Q_m(n)}.$

For the first family, $P_m(0)=m^2$,$Q_m(0)=1$, $P_m(1)=Q_m(1)=2^{k(m)}$, and  Sidharth Ghoshal also noticed that the values of $$\left|\frac{Q_{m+1}(I)}{Q_m(I)}\right|=12,144,144, 1728, 1728, 20736, 20736$$ for $2 \leq m\leq 8$ are  all powers of $12$. A natural question may be asked: what are the values of $$P_m(n),Q_m(n)$$
where $n=I,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+I)$? We have the following

**Identitiy 1.** $$P_m(I)=(-1)^{\frac{k(m+2)}{4}}12^{\frac{k(m)}{4}},$$
$$Q_m(I)=(-12)^{\frac{k(m)}{4}},$$
where $k(m)= 2 {\lfloor \frac{m^{2}}{2}\rfloor}.$

I have verified it for  $1\leq m \leq 16.$

**Identitiy 2.** $$P_m\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+I)\right)=
\begin{cases}
    6^{\frac{m^2}{4}}I, & \text{if } m \equiv 0\pmod{4} \\
    -6^{\frac{m^2}{4}}, & \text{if } m \equiv 2\pmod{4} \\
    6^{\frac{m^2-1}{4}}(\lambda(m)+(\lambda(m)-1)I), & \text{if } m \equiv 1,7\pmod{8} \\
    6^{\frac{m^2-1}{4}}(-\lambda(m)-(\lambda(m)-1)I), & \text{if } m \equiv 3,5\pmod{8}
\end{cases},$$
$$Q_m\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+I)\right)=
 \begin{cases}
    6^{\frac{m^2}{4}}, & \text{if } m \equiv 0\pmod{4} \\
    6^{\frac{m^2}{4}}I, & \text{if } m \equiv 2\pmod{4} \\
    6^{\frac{m^2-1}{4}}(\lambda(m)-(\lambda(m)-1)I), & \text{if } m \equiv 1,7\pmod{8} \\
    6^{\frac{m^2-1}{4}}(-\lambda(m)+(\lambda(m)-1)I), & \text{if } m \equiv 3,5\pmod{8}
\end{cases}
,$$
where $\lambda(m)= a_{\frac{m+1}{2}}=1, 5, 45, 441, 4361, 43165, 427285, 4229681,\cdots$(see https://oeis.org/A054318)

i.e, $$\lambda(m)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}\right)^{m} \sqrt{3}}{12}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\right)^{m} \sqrt{3}}{12}.$$
I have verified it for  $1\leq m \leq 16.$

For the second family, I think there are some similar identities.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I've verified that for $b_{10}$, the the sum of its coefficients is $2^{100}$ while for $b_{11}$ it is $2^{120}$, consistent with the results for previous $b_m$. If you state it can be done for **ALL** $m$, then that answers part of my question. How did you do it though? Did you use $2P, 3P, 4P, 5P$, etc, so a one-to-one correspondence to the $b_m$?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. And I was just going to suggest to change $b_n \to b_m$ since you already used the variable $n$ in the elliptic curve $E_1$.

Comment: The same elliptic curve, $$(a^3 - b) (b^3 - a) = y^2$$ also has a _second_ family of solutions when $a=n^3,$ namely, $$b_1 =n\,\frac{(1 - 2n^2 + n^4 + n^6)}{(1 + n^2 - 2n^4 + n^6)}$$ We may have found the first three points. Can you verify if we didn't skip one? See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4780738/4781).

Comment: @Deyi Chen, How did you find $P=\left(3 n^{2}+1, -2 n^{6}-\frac{1}{2} n^{4}-5 n^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Comment: Transform the point $(b_2,y) \in E_1$ to $P\in E_2$.

Comment: @DeyiChen I have trimmed the post as its file size was getting too large and the page was loading too slow. Also, you don't have the sums of the coefficients of the **second** family. Kindly check.

Comment: @DeyiChen Thanks for adding the info. So the sums of the coefficients of the first and second family are the SAME. That is certainly interesting!

Comment: In fact, I calculated the sum of the coefficients for the second family first, and found that there was only one difference from the first  family's without modifying $b_1$, so I modified $b_1$.

Comment: @DeyiChen I also modified the $b_1$ and table in my post and credited it to you. It was useful to consider both families at the same time, as Ghoshal and you noticed a pattern for the two, and you found an additional relation between the degrees of the denominators of the two. Seems a lot of mysteries for the simple equation $x^4+y^4=z^4+w^4$!

Comment: @Deyi the software has flagged this for excessive edits. It might be better to assemble further edits into a document hosted offside, and link to it here. The MathJax really struggles with such big formulas.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I also noticed how MathJax struggled. In fact, I already trimmed away some of Devi's longest formulas before. Do you want me to trim some more? (P.S. I also did it to some of my own formulas in the question.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII well, up to you. (I appreciate the cleaning up). I just wanted to point out to Deyi that continuing to make incremental edits is going to keep bumping this to the top of the front page, and that is not seen as playing fair by MO standards. So if you two could communicate by email or whatever to continue this discussion/line of research that might be helpful. Or even in a chat room here on MO.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Answer has now been trimmed more. I looked at his profile, and maybe he is just not familiar with the norms of MO. But I do appreciate the great work and observations he's done.

Comment: @DeyiChen You may like [this new MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852495/still-more-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4-d4). It is about elliptic curves and $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is using pieces from my related answer to the related question [MSE question 4779869](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779869/finding-rational-points-on-the-elliptic-curve-for-a4b4-c4d4),
where many details to the computations below are shown. Some simple blocks of sage code collect
experimentally all $b$-polynomials involved. The results are tabulated - as much as the MSE site permits to do.
This answer gives proofs. Some details are missing, in order to have a complete proof, but the path / the story should be clear.

---

We start with the equation
$$v^2 =(a^3-b)(b^3-a)\ ,$$
considered over the function field $\Bbb Q(a)$.
Instead of furthermore using a specialization $a=n$. I will work with $a=A$ to make this specialization
"fixed" in notation. Also, i will use $u$ instead of $b$. So we deal with the curve:
$$
C=C(A)=C(A)_{u,v}\ :\qquad v^2 =(u^3-A)(A^3-u)\ .
$$
As explained in *loc. cit.* (MSE), we move birationally
$(u,v)\leftrightarrow (x,y)$, and in it in fact $u\leftrightarrow x$ only, via
$x=c/(A^3 - u) - A^6$, $u=A^3-c/(x+A^6)$, $c:=A^9-A$,
to the elliptic curve
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad
E=E(A)=E(A)_{x,y}\ :\qquad\qquad y^2 = x^3 - 3A^4x - A^2(A^8+1)\ .
\qquad
}
$$
Dividing by $A^6$, the obvious substitutions lead to the form:
$$
Y^2 = X^3 - 3X +\left(A^4+\bar A^4\right)\ .
$$
(A bar is used for the inverse.)

Here we have the reciprocal symmetry explicitly shown, and the particular solution
$X=A^2+1+\bar A^2$, resp. $x=A^4 + A^2 +1$ can be checked. It corresponds to $u=a$.
For $x$ consider the lift $G=G(A)$ on $E(A)$ given by
$$
G(A) = (A^4 + A^2 + 1, \ A^6 + A^4 + A^2 +1)\ .
$$
Then the many rational functions $b_k(A)$ from the question (with $A=n$) occur in the following manner.
Start with $G(A)$. Build $kG(A)=(x_k(A),y_k(A))\in E(\ \Bbb Q(A)\ )$, extract $x_k(A)$ and pass from
$E$ to $C$ to obtain $u_k(A)=b_k(A)$ and the corresponding $v_k(A)$.

In the sequel we need the addition formula for points of the above curve.
Given $P_1,P_2$, the sum is $P_3$ - all points being of the shape $P_k=(x_k,y_k)\ne \infty$ - we have:
$$
\tag{$*$}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_3 &= -x_1-x_2 +\lambda^2\ ,\\
y_3 &= -y_1 -(x_3-x_1)\lambda\,\qquad\text{ where $\lambda$ is the slope }\lambda=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
\end{aligned}
$$
in the case of $x_1\ne x_2$, and else we pass to the limit, $x_3=(3x_1^2-3A^4)/y_1$.

---

It may be useful to record some relations for the passage from one world to the other one, in between notations as in MSE:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u &=A^3 -\frac 1{x_1}=A^3-\frac c{x_2}=A^3-\frac c{x+A^6}=\frac {A^3x+A}{x+A^6}
=\begin{bmatrix} A^3 & A \\ 1 & A^6\end{bmatrix}\cdot x\ ,\\
x &= x_2-A^6 =cx_1-A^6=\frac c{A^3-u}-A^6=\frac{A^6u-A}{-u+A^3}
=\begin{bmatrix} A^6 & -A \\ -1 & A^3\end{bmatrix}\cdot u\ ,\\
v &=\frac{y_1}{x_1^2}=\frac {y_1}c\cdot\frac{c^2}{x_2^2}=\frac{cy}{(x+A^6)^2}\ ,\\
y &= y_2=cy_1=cvx_1^2=\frac {cv}{(A^3-u)^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

> **Questions:**
>
> - **(i)** Consider $b_k(A)/A$. Is this expression of the shape $B_k(A, 1)/B_k(1,A)$
>   for some homogeneous polynomial $B_k$? If yes, we may and do assume below that it is normed so that $B_k(A,1)$ is monic, i.e. $B_k(1,0)=1$.
> - **(ii)** If yes, what is $B_k(0, 1)$, the free coefficient of $B_k(A,1)$?
> - **(iii)** If yes, what is $B_k(1, 1)$, the sum of the coefficients of $B_k$?

---

Answers to the questions are following.
Let us assume **(i)**. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_k(A)
&=
\frac c{A^3-u_k(A)}-A^6
=
\frac {A^9-A}{A^3-u_k(A)}-A^6
=
\frac {A^8-1}{A^2-\frac{B_k(A,1)}{B_k(1,A)}}-A^6
\\
&\overset{A\to 0}\longrightarrow
\frac {0-1}{0-\frac{B_k(A,1)}{B_k(1,A)}}-0=\frac 1{B_k(0,1)}
\end{aligned}
$$
To show now the formula claimed on experimental data in the OP
$$
\bbox[yellow]{
  \qquad
  B_k(0,1)={\color{red}{k^2}}
  \qquad
}
$$
it is **enough** to show:

**Lemma:** Consider $x_k(A)$, $y_k(A)$ as rational functions of $A$.
Then zero is not a pole and not a zero for them, and we have moreover:
$$
x_k(0)=\frac 1{\color{red}{k^2}}\ ,\qquad y_k(0)=\frac 1{k^3}\ .
$$

The above can be easily checked for the first few values of $k$,
let us have explicit samples:
$$\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
$$
\small
\begin{aligned}
(x_1,y_1) &= G=(A^4 + A^2 + 1,\ A^6 + A^4 + A^2 + 1)\ ,\\
(x_2,y_2) &= 2G=\left(
\frac 1{\color{red}4}(A^4 + 10A^2 + 1),\  \frac 18(A^6 - 17A^4 - 17A^2 + 1)\right)
\ ,\\
(x_3,y_3) &= 3G
\\
&= \left(
\frac{A^{12} + 101 A^{10} + 291 A^8 + 238 A^6 + 291 A^4 + 101 A^2 + 1}
{{\color{red}9} (A^2 - 1)^4 }\ ,\right.
\\
&\qquad\left.
\
\frac{
(A^{12} - 214 A^{10} - 2481 A^8 - 2804 A^6 - 2481 A^4 - 214 A^2 + 1)
(A^4 + 1)
(A^2 + 1)}
{27 (A^2 - 1)^6}
\right)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on.

*Proof of the lemma:* For $k=1,2$ things are checked. Assume by induction the formula holds for some $k\ge 2$.
Then the addition law (*) on the curve computed for $(k+1)G=G+kG$, then evaluated in $A=0$ gives:
$$
\small
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_k(0) &:= \frac{y_1-y_k}{x_1-x_k}(0)=\frac{1-\frac 1{k^3}}{1-\frac 1{k^2}}=1 + \frac 1{k(k+1)}\ .
\\
x_{k+1}(0) &= -x_1(0)-x_k(0)+\lambda_k^2(0)=-1-\frac 1{k^2}+ \left(1 + \frac 1{k(k+1)}\right)^2=\frac 1{\color{red}{(k+1)^2}}\ ,\\
y_{k+1}(0) &= -y_1(0)-(x_{k+1}(0)-x_1(0))\lambda_k(0)
=-1-\left(\frac 1{(k+1)^2-1}\right)\cdot\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)}
\\
&=-1+\frac{(k+2)(k^2+k+1))}{(k+1)^3}=\frac 1{(k+1)^3}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

We have so far modulo the mirror property **(i)** the formula **(ii)**, which was the target as i started to type.
(Soon **(iii)** also was in there.)

---

So let us show **(ii)**. The sample values for $x_k,y_k$ above motivate the following

**Lemma:** The rational functions $x_k(A)$, $y_k(A)$ use symmetric polynomials in their numerator
and denominator (for suitable representations). Their total $A$-degree (at $\infty$ is $4$, respectively $6$.

*Proof:* Use the symmetry in the $(X,Y)$ world, then come back to the $(x,y)$ world.

$\square$

---

The main step is:

> **Lemma:** For all $k\ge 1$ we have $x_k=p_k/q_k$ with **reciprocal polynomials**
> $p_k,q_k=d_k^2$. Let $P_k,Q_k$ be the homogenized versions of $p_k,q_k$.
> Then there exist further homogeneous polynomials $B_k,V_k$ with
> $$
> \bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
> \begin{aligned}
> u_k(A) &= A\cdot \frac {B_k(A,1)}{B_k(1,A)}=\frac{A^2P_k(A,1) + Q_k(A,1)}{A^6Q(A,1) +P(A,1)}\ ,\\
> v_k(A) &= A\cdot \frac {V_k(A,1)}{B^2_k(1,A)}\ ,
> \end{aligned}\qquad}
> $$
> Explicitly:
> $$
> \bbox[lightyellow]{
>   \qquad
> b_k(A)=B_k(A,1)$ \text{ is a factor of }a^2p_k(A)+ q_k(A)\ ,\qquad p_k,q_k\text{ reciprocal.}
> \qquad
> }
> $$
> The above factor is obtained after the simplification of the fraction $(A^2p_k+q_k)/(A^6q_k+p_k)$.
> A **known simplification** occurs for $k=3j$, when both $(A^2p_k+q_k)$ and
> $A^6q_k +p_k$ are divisible by the
> $$\color{blue}{
>   \text{Known factor: }(A^6+A^4+A^2+1)
> }
> \ .
> $$
> Moreover, $V_k$ is antisymmetric, $V_k(s,t)=-V_k(t,s)$.

As an illustration let us plot the involved polynomials for first small $k$ values.
(For bigger values use the linked code.)

For $k=1$ we have $u_1=b_1=A$, and $v_1=A^3-A$, $B_1=1$, $V_1(A,1)= A^2-1$.
And indeed, $V_1(s,t)=s^2-t^2=-(t^2-s^2)=-V_1(t,s)$.

For $k=2$ computations deliver
$x_2=\frac 14(A^4+10A^2+1)$,
$u_2=b_2=A\cdot B_2(n,1)/B_2(1,n)$ with
$$
B_2(n,1)= n^6 + 10n^4 + n^2 + 4\ ,
$$
and $v_2=A\cdot V_2(n,1)/B_2(1,n)^2$
with
$$V_2(n,1)=2n^{14} - 34n^{12} - 34n^{10} + 2n^{8} - 2n^{6} + 34n^{4} + 34n^{2} - 2\ .$$

Further experimental data are on parallel answers, and/or in my linked MSE-post.

*Proof:* We show only what we need, the formula for $u_k$. (Olny $B$-computations, no $V$-computation.)

Recall that $x_k$ has a representation as $P(A,1)/Q(A,1)$ with degree $4$,
so $\deg P=4+d$ for some $d$, and $\deg Q =d$.
One can see inductively, that only even powers occur.
Then
$$
u_k =
\begin{bmatrix} A^3 & A \\ 1 & A^6\end{bmatrix}\cdot \frac PQ
=A\cdot \frac{A^2P(A,1)+Q(A,1)}{A^6Q(A,1) + P(A,1)}
\ .
$$
To have a better image, let us put the coefficients of $A^2P, Q; A^6Q, P$ on parallel lines.

The coefficients of $P$ are $p_0,p_1=0,p_2,\dots,p_2,p_1=0,p_0$. They are corresponding to degree $4+d$.
The coefficients of $Q$ are similarly $q_0,q_1=0,q_2,\dots,q_2,q_1=0,q_0$.

Then the numerator has coefficients:

```
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 ......... a7 a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0  0  0   --- from A^2 P
 0  0  0  0  0  0 q0 .........    q8 q7 q6 q5 q4 q3 q2 q1 q0   --- from     Q
```

And the denominator has the coefficients:

```
q0 q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 ....         q0  0  0  0  0  0  0   --- from A^6 Q
 0  0 a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a4 a6 ....         a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0   --- from     P
```

It is clear that the claimed reciprocity holds,
the numerators makes a polynomial $B(A,1)=A^2P(A,1)+Q(A,1)$, and
the denominator is exactly $B(1,A)=A^6Q(A,1) +P(A,1)$.

This shows **(i)**, and thus the formula for the free coefficient
$\color{red}{k^2}$ in the numerator of $b_k$ is proven.

$\square$

---

It remains **(iii)**.
I will invest some typing effort to show the path.

For this, note that we need in the last notation
$B(1,1)=P(1,1)+Q(1,1)$.
So we want to specialize $A=1$. The corresponding "limit curve"
$y^2=x^3 -3x-2$
is no longer elliptic,
so the group law degenerates and can be easily examined.
I will say some words in this EDITED answer on this.

It may be also of interest to obtain an explicit recursion for the polynomials $B$.
Computations need specific data.
We define homogeneous polynomials $P_k,D_k,R_k$ with dehomogenized versions $p_k,d_k,r_k$,
that appear in $kG=(x_k(A),y_k(A))$, $k\ge 1$,
$$
x_k(A)=\frac {p_k(A)}{d_k(A)^2}\ ,\qquad
y_k(A)=\frac {r_k(A)}{d_k(A)^3}\ ,
$$
where the base factor $d_k(A)$ of the denominators is relatively prime to the monic numerators
$p_k,q_k$
of $x_k,y_k$.
The recursion starts with the values:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1 &= A^4 + A^2 +1\ , & r_1 &= A^6 + A^4 + A^2 + 1\ , & d_1 = 1\ ,\\
p_2 &= A^4 + 10A^2 +1\ , & r_2 &= (A^2 + 1)(A^2 - 4A - 1)(A^2 + 4A - 1)\ , & d_2 = 2\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and the recursion step is determined by applying the formula $(*)$, with an in between step of computing
the slopes $\lambda_k$. We will decide later which is the recursion step $s$. (It may be one, two, three, six,
depending on the joy of typing arguments and the specific purpose.)
Formulas are easily written:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x_{k+s}, y_{k+s}) &= (k+s)G=kG\oplus sG=(x_k,y_k)\oplus(x_s,y_s)\ ,
\\
\lambda_k=\lambda_{k,s}
&:=
\frac {y_k-y_s}{x_k-x_s}
=
\frac 1{d_k}\cdot\frac{r_k -y_s d_k^3}{p_k - x_s d_k^2}\ ,
\\
\frac{p_{k+s}}{d_{k+s}^2}
&=x_{k+s}
\\
&=-x_s-x_k+\lambda_k^2
\\
&=-x_s-\frac{p_k}{d_k^2}+
\frac 1{d_k^2}\cdot\frac{(r_k -y_sd_k^3)^2}{(p_k-x_s d_k^2)^2}
\ ,
\\
\frac{r_{k+s}}{d_{k+s}^3}
&=y_{k+s}
\\
&=-y_s-(x_{k+s}-x_s)\lambda_k\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
From here extract the recursion formula for $d_{k+s}$, $p_{k+s}$, $r_{k+s}$.
Finally consider the homogenized versions $D_k,P_k,R_k$, and set:
$$
B_k = \underbrace{(A^2P_k + D_k^2)}_{B_k^*}/\text{factor}\ .
$$
Here the factor is the gcd of $B_k^*:=(A^2P_k+Q_k)$ and $(A^2Q_k+P_k)$, as in the Main Lemma.
We have a known factor.
No further multiplicative cancellation occurs in the experiments with small numbers $k$,
but if they occur we do not implement them here, sorry.
This is the only missing point, and let us address it as a "gap".

The table for the degrees is:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
k                         & 1 & 2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &   9 &  10 \\\hline
\deg d_k                  & 0 & 0 &  4 &  6 & 12 & 16 & 24 & 30 &  40 &  48 \\\hline
\deg p_k = 2\deg d_k + 4  & 4 & 4 & 12 & 16 & 28 & 36 & 52 & 64 &  84 & 100 \\\hline
\deg r_k = 3\deg d_k + 6  & 6 & 6 & 18 & 24 & 42 & 54 & 78 & 96 & 126 & 150 \\\hline
\deg B_k                  & 1 & 6 &  8 & 18 & 24 & 38 & 48 & 66 &  80 & 102 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

> ---

A one-step recursion would not take care of the fact that the degree drops
by chance for $k=1$, and this propagates now with step two. So we may want to use the step two
while giving the one or the other proof.
Let us break into
two cases for the above reason, odd and even values of $k$.

> ---

- $k$ odd:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
k                                  & 1 &  3 &  5 &  7 &   9 &   11 &  13  &  15 &  17 &  19 \\\hline
\deg d_k                           & 0 &  4 & 12 & 24 &  40 &   60 &  84  & 112 & 144 & 180 \\\hline
\deg p_k = 2\deg d_k + 4           & 4 & 12 & 28 & 52 &  84 &  124 & 172  & 228 & 292 & 364 \\\hline
\deg r_k = 3\deg d_k + 6           & 6 & 18 & 42 & 78 & 126 &  186 & 258  & 342 & 438 & 546 \\\hline
\deg B_k = 2\deg d_k + \delta_{k1}  & 1 &  8 & 24 & 48 &  80 & 120 & 168  & 224 & 288 & 360 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
The extracted formulas are:
$$
\tag{$k$ odd $\ge1$}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\deg d_k &= \frac 12(k^2-1)\ ,\\
\deg p_k &= (k^2+3)\ ,\\
\deg r_k &= \frac 32(k^2+3)\ ,\\
\deg B_k &= k^2-1=2\deg d_k\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which can be tested inductively starting from $k=3$ with step two modulo the "gap".

> ---

- $k$ even:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
k                         & 2 &  4 &  6 &  8 &   10 &   12 &  14 &  16  &  18 \\\hline
\deg d_k                  & 0 &  6 & 16 & 30 &   48 &   70 &  96 & 126  & 160 \\\hline
\deg p_k = 2\deg d_k + 4  & 4 & 16 & 36 & 64 &  100 &  144 & 196 & 256  & 324 \\\hline
\deg r_k = 3\deg d_k + 6  & 6 & 24 & 54 & 96 &  150 &  216 & 294 & 384  & 486 \\\hline
\deg B_k = 2\deg d_k + 6  & 6 & 18 & 38 & 66 &  102 &  146 & 198 & 258  & 326 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
And the pattern is:
$$
\tag{$k$ even $\ge2$}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\deg d_k &= \frac 12(k^2-4)\ ,\\
\deg p_k &= k^2\ ,\\
\deg r_k &= \frac 32 k^2\ ,\\
\deg B_k &= k^2+2\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which can also be tested inductively.
All the above modulo the "gap".

---

This is a line break in the proof of **(iii)**, recall what we have so far.
Some chain of polynomials $d,p,r;B$ have been constructed, indexed by $k$,
so that $p/d^2$ and $r/d^3$ reproduce the multiples of $G$ as elements in $E(A)(\ \Bbb Q(A)\ )$,
they are defined recursively using only ring operations. The situation
so far allows to evaluate all the polynomials in the point one.
Then $k\cdot G(1)$ makes no sense any longer, since $E(1)$ is not an elliptic curve,
but the operations involving the polynomials $d,p,r;B$ do make sense, when evaluated in one.
Now i have to say something, and the best claim i can make in this framework is to
use experimental data, based on it make short sentences.
We simply plot the values of the $d,p,r,b$ polynomials, when computed in one.
I am providing the sage code, since it is simple:

```
def EA(A, field=QQ):
    return EllipticCurve(field, [-3*A^4, -A^10 - A^2])

R0.<n> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
F = FractionField(R0)
E = EA(n, field=F)
G = E.point([n^4 + n^2 + 1, n^6 + n^4 + n^2 + 1])

for k in [1..20]:
    xk, yk = (k*G).xy()    # xk, yk are in F, rational functions of n
    dk = R0( sqrt(xk.denominator()) ) 
    pk = R0(      xk.numerator()    )
    rk = R0(      yk.numerator()    )
    Bk = (n^3 - (n^9 - n)/(xk + n^6)).numerator()

    dk1, pk1, rk1, Bk1 = dk(1), pk(1), rk(1), Bk(1)
    Bk1_formula = pk1 + dk1^2

    info = ' & '.join([latex(factor(expr)) if expr else str(expr)
                       for expr in (dk1, pk1, rk1, Bk1, Bk1_formula)])
    print(f"{k} & {info}\\\\\\hline")
```

And we obtain:
$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|l|}
  \hline
  k & d_k(1) & p_k(1) & r_k(1) & b_k(1)=B_k(1,1) & p_k(1) +d_k^2(1)\\\hline 
1 & 1 & 3 & 2^{2} & 1 & 2^{2}\\\hline
2 & 2 & 2^{2} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{5} & 2^{4} & 2^{4}\\\hline
3 & 0 & 2^{10} & 2^{15} & \color{blue}{2^{8}} & 2^{10}\\\hline
4 & -1 \cdot 2^{7} & 2^{14} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{23} & 2^{16} & 2^{16}\\\hline
5 & -1 \cdot 2^{12} & 2^{24} \cdot 3 & 2^{38} & 2^{24} & 2^{26}\\\hline
6 & 0 & 2^{36} & 2^{54} & 2^{36} & 2^{36}\\\hline
7 & 2^{24} & 2^{48} \cdot 3 & 2^{74} & 2^{48} & 2^{50}\\\hline
8 & 2^{31} & 2^{62} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{95} & 2^{64} & 2^{64}\\\hline
9 & 0 & 2^{82} & -1 \cdot 2^{123} & \color{blue}{2^{80}} & 2^{82}\\\hline
10 & -1 \cdot 2^{49} & 2^{98} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{149} & 2^{100} & 2^{100}\\\hline
11 & -1 \cdot 2^{60} & 2^{120} \cdot 3 & 2^{182} & 2^{120} & 2^{122}\\\hline
12 & 0 & 2^{144} & 2^{216} & 2^{144} & 2^{144}\\\hline
13 & 2^{84} & 2^{168} \cdot 3 & 2^{254} & 2^{168} & 2^{170}\\\hline
14 & 2^{97} & 2^{194} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{293} & 2^{196} & 2^{196}\\\hline
15 & 0 & 2^{226} & -1 \cdot 2^{339} & \color{blue}{2^{224}} & 2^{226}\\\hline
16 & -1 \cdot 2^{127} & 2^{254} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{383} & 2^{256} & 2^{256}\\\hline
17 & -1 \cdot 2^{144} & 2^{288} \cdot 3 & 2^{434} & 2^{288} & 2^{290}\\\hline
18 & 0 & 2^{324} & 2^{486} & 2^{324} & 2^{324}\\\hline
19 & 2^{180} & 2^{360} \cdot 3 & 2^{542} & 2^{360} & 2^{362}\\\hline
20 & 2^{199} & 2^{398} \cdot 3 & -1 \cdot 2^{599} & 2^{400} & 2^{400}\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
All the above, for it is easier for me to make sentences now.
The last two columns almost agree for $k\ge 2$, this is just a check of the claimed formula for $B_k$
in terms of $P_k$ and $D_k$. The blue differences come from the "known factor" (from the **Main Lemma**),
it is $\color{blue}{(A^6+A^4+A^2+1)_{\text{in }A=1} = 1+1+1+1=4}$.

For $k$ a multiple of $3$ the denominator vanishes in one.
(So for some arguments the induction / recursion has a convenient step three. Or maybe six.)
For the proof of this fact, note that the expression $(\dagger)$ for $3G$ comes with denominators
which are powers of
$d_3(A)=3(A^2-1)^2$. Simple code gives for $d_6(A)$ the expression
$$
\small
2 \cdot 3 \cdot (A - 1)^{2} \cdot (A + 1)^{2} \cdot (A^{12} - 214A^{10} - 2481A^{8} - 2804A^{6} - 2481A^{4} - 214A^{2} + 1)\ .
$$
By induction, $d_{3k}(A)$ has a zero of order two in $A=1$.
To have a better argument for the vanishing, note that the specialization $A=0$
leads to multiples of $G$ with non-vanishing $y$-component. So let switch the view in the curve
$E(A)$ from the afine $(x,y)$ perspective with $z=1$ to the $(X,Z)$ perspective with $Y=1$,
so that in the projective space we have $[x:y:1]=[X:1:Z]$.
Then we have in parallel:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&E(A)_{x,y}\ :\ & y^2 &= x^3 -3A^2x - A^2(A^8+1)           \ , \\
&E(A)_{X,Z}\ :\ &   Z &= X^3 -3A^2XZ^2 - a^2(A^8+1)Z^3     \ , \\[2mm]
&E(1)_{x,y}\ :\ & y^2 &= x^3 -3x - 2 = (x-2)(x+1)^2         \ , \\
&E(1)_{X,Z}\ :\ &   Z &= X^3 -3XZ^2 -2Z^3 = (X-2Z)(X+Z)^2  \ , \\[2mm]
&& \infty(A)_{x,y} &= [0:1:0]= \infty     \ ,\\
&& \infty(A)_{X,Z} &= [0:1:0]=(0,0)_{X,Z} \ ,\\[2mm]
&& G(1)_{x,y} &= (3,4) = [3:4:1]\ ,\\
&& G(1)_{X,Z} &= [3:4:1]=\left(\frac 34,\frac 14\right)_{X,Z}\ ,\\
&& (2G)(A=1)_{x,y} &= (3,-4) = [3:-4:1]\ ,\\
&& (2G)(A=1)_{X,Z} &= [3:-4:1]=\left(-\frac 34,-\frac 14\right)_{X,Z}\ ,\\
&& (3G)(A=1)_{x,y} &= \infty = [0:1:0]\ ,\\
&& (3G)(A=1)_{X,Z} &= [0:1:0]=(0,0)_{X,Z}\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and from here, we can continue the computation of $(kG)$ computed in $A=1$ using the same
geometric definition of multiples on the degenerated elliptic curve $E(1)$, as we do on $E(A)$ over $\Bbb Q(A)$.
For instance, in order to compute $(4G)_{X,Z}$ in $A=1$ we intersect the line through $G(A=1)=(3/4,1/4)_{X,Z}$
and $(3G)(A=1)=(0,0)_{X,Z}$ -- which is $X=3Z$ -- with the cubic $E(1)$.
The substitution of $X=3Z$ into the equation of $E(1)$ gives in $Z$ the equation $Z=(27-9-2)Z^3=16Z^3$, so $Z$ is among
$0,\pm \frac14$. The third point on the line and the curve has $Z=-1/4$, corresponding to $(-3/4,-1/4)_{X,Z}$,
and it remains to draw through this last point and the infinity point, intersect once more to get $G$ again.
We have the repetition after three steps, so the $X$-component always vanishes for $3kG(A=1)$, so the
corresponding $x$-component vanishes.

This shows that the point $(x,y)=(p/d^2,r/d^3)=[pd:r:d^3]$ is always among $[3:4:1]$, $[3:-4:1]$, $[0:1:0]$.
The period for the pattern is three.

An inductive argument shows that - modulo the "gap" - we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
k &= 6j + 0 & d_k(1) &= 0\ ,\\
  &         & p_k(1) &= 2^{k^2}\ ,\\
  &         & r_k(1) &= 2^{3k^2/2} = p_k(1)^{3/2}\ ,\\
  &         & b_k(1) &= p_k(1)+d_k(1)^2=2^{k^2}\ ,
\\[2mm]
k &= 6j + 1 & d_k(1) &= 2^{(k^2-1)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & p_k(1) &= 3\cdot 2^{k^2-1}=3d_k(1)^2\ ,\\
  &         & r_k(1) &= 2^{(3k^2+1)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & b_k(1) &= p_k(1)+d_k(1)^2=2^{k^2+1}\ ,
\\[2mm]
k &= 6j + 2 & d_k(1) &= 2^{(k^2-2)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & p_k(1) &= 3\cdot 2^{k^2-2}=3d_k(1)^2\ ,\\
  &         & r_k(1) &= -2^{(3k^2-2)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & b_k(1) &= p_k(1)+d_k(1)^2=2^{k^2}\ ,
\\[2mm]
k &= 6j + 3 & d_k(1) &= 0\ ,\\
  &         & p_k(1) &= 2^{k^2+1}\ ,\\
  &         & r_k(1) &= -2^{3(k^2+1)/2} = -p_k(1)^{3/2}\ ,\\
  &         & b_k(1) &= 2^{k^2-1}=(p_k(1)+d_k(1)^2)\color{blue}{/4} = p_k(1)\color{blue}{/4}\ ,
\\[2mm]
k &= 6j + 4 & d_k(1) &= -2^{(k^2-2)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & p_k(1) &= 3\cdot 2^{k^2-2}=3d_k(1)^2\ ,\\
  &         & r_k(1) &= -2^{(3k^2-2)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & b_k(1) &= p_k(1)+d_k(1)^2=2^{k^2}\ ,
\\[2mm]
k &= 6j + 5 & d_k(1) &= -2^{(k^2-1)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & p_k(1) &= 3\cdot 2^{k^2-1}=3d_k(1)^2\ ,\\
  &         & r_k(1) &= 2^{(3k^2+1)/2}\ ,\\
  &         & b_k(1) &= p_k(1)+d_k(1)^2=2^{k^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The above shows how the arithmetic information is
covered in $d_k$, in case it is not vanishing,
then $p_k,r_k$ are constrained to be $p_k=3d_k^2$, and $(-1)^{k-1} 4d_k^3$.

---

---

Some simple sage code may be of interest, it computes the $B$-polynomials (and implicitly all data in between. Please adapt to see other wanted variables with corresponding prints.)
Similar pieces of code that compute "more" and for different purposes
are on my MSE answer(s).

```
def EA(A, field=QQ):
    return EllipticCurve(field, [-3*A^4, -A^10 - A^2])

R0.<n> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
F = FractionField(R0)
E = EA(n, field=F)
G = E.point([n^4 + n^2 + 1, n^6 + n^4 + n^2 + 1])

def B(k):
    a = n
    x = (k*G)[0]
    u = a^3 - (a^9 - a)/(x + a^6)
    b = u
    # v = sqrt( (a^3 - b)*(b^3 - a) )

    B = R0( (b/n).numerator() ).homogenize()
    if b == n * B(n, 1) / B(1, n):
        return B(n, 1)

# we may want to compute some B(k) for some relatively big k
print(f"B(13) = {latex(B(13))}")
```

And the above delivers:

$$
\tiny
B(13) = n^{168} + 643636n^{166} + 5416986934n^{164} - 6595169725244n^{162} + 20823931764302085n^{160} + 2875645846603778256n^{158} + 1667712145664558474856n^{156} + 159719934229962104174544n^{154} - 16418235274964244829099494n^{152} + 954887218043767314805499448n^{150} + 119731846710387314592686553492n^{148} + 3545291054165619315617657176152n^{146} + 121504163937978834746972642259210n^{144} + 3483488952052995289250579056814736n^{142} + 83193822695689099812768800490620328n^{140} + 963669940858723246664288414820239376n^{138} + 5691469353214542915269951938210105161n^{136} + 34636022418791988733051310409079244676n^{134} + 772541505470326563462542035514293522878n^{132} + 12825827388403891535299751323799386857108n^{130} + 138375990668894146984438432219206293217189n^{128} + 1133788329625647602603370172507874631269952n^{126} + 7592111666637440834997403231308573289580064n^{124} + 43764898682113299066393550990233916516372032n^{122} + 220209983529714884603307386851596893018428056n^{120} + 964750413127091863839044880196438110773385120n^{118} + 3687661350705896058636957906339919636823931888n^{116} + 12401212124649612962711080846137647902633076512n^{114} + 37170447403151095547819375350251357999929628184n^{112} + 100558209997856791867475940285188752412545861696n^{110} + 248161480118927171797911195972622236332506749088n^{108} + 563180918961626841685377680475438225636927001152n^{106} + 1182200905381161473183913287890740359064114659202n^{104} + 2303517567013892455193606912279403544735275537192n^{102} + 4176619501453304059258890215236080772082409113292n^{100} + 7054672921795819076752476136496891377159205078088n^{98} + 11110486539818301367775609188302841995113100887274n^{96} + 16320842530963850967065747412813453323987341073760n^{94} + 22369933935840320524337471821250807854472109461424n^{92} + 28613368251106838111952897091956658826075046771552n^{90} + 34161418782068102116676283742638185275584785620668n^{88} + 38067666977807856406875432807516827053194535910736n^{86} + 39591896044137661357489144863004740708845299012344n^{84} + 38416428184074426024353311084072898577233512604688n^{82} + 34758529974089937437794383641742859184577458327196n^{80} + 29295902751838084379673739856980382438415938704608n^{78} + 22971124728627050111639034597162544229637487183536n^{76} + 16724561176091393920903041897975104152397111166432n^{74} + 11277526309480866434237969013007318587784647334746n^{72} + 7019642047412867390482205533910867351330296121064n^{70} + 4015198416796069582405560580736721363005646871116n^{68} + 2098714389423006258602615266138135065936380182920n^{66} + 994739957392593453251893263108577583908969756626n^{64} + 423353217820373867605601641881099107708577721152n^{62} + 159535773297002729507424474343153022492340924064n^{60} + 52182270960305643285335423308984192212446749504n^{58} + 14348595244558616092247378416556523542802658648n^{56} + 3127138039859359323247812486544851441415556512n^{54} + 467690447726443685407311684343560305168336880n^{52} + 21997995433324589748997186648535586518194464n^{50} - 8114465233693039008333355772108118158268072n^{48} - 684223605949013017419151498549204480745664n^{46} + 1077917101896619148096733705656236255590432n^{44} + 570615057602475835936996367920813091645760n^{42} + 162025245456359277677940854988272484389277n^{40} + 30607069413717696641244864966871424783268n^{38} + 4174844335887760703273324515919511090174n^{36} + 436477806016997976391827054641725899252n^{34} + 35548978009085705306173155297537417201n^{32} + 1927492454500235987135304419497529424n^{30} + 61328816631688764307329243196871976n^{28} - 402516608559576880843779649143984n^{26} - 212640181426567207064206638104262n^{24} - 7095123653702930401996019826888n^{22} + 73964684163965477297514101652n^{20} + 3136114410853974725886870360n^{18} + 97009175247955676705825514n^{16} + 711325305233993038133520n^{14} + 5666753838034609840872n^{12} - 33680411373627173232n^{10} - 20879330408465859n^{8} + 107551370047636n^{6} + 84462003190n^{4} - 7758620n^{2} + \color{red}{169}\ .
$$

It is of course simple to compute the value in $1$ or in $i$ or in a primitive $8$.th root $u$.
Why these values? Since the discriminant of $E(A)$ is (up to factor)
$$
4\Big( -3A^4\Big)^3 + 27\Big(-A^2(A^8+1)\Big)^2
=27A^4(A^8-1)^2\ ,
$$
so specializing to a root of unity of order (dividing) $8$ leads to a degeneration.

Here is the list of the first few specializations:

```
u = QQbar( cos(2*pi/8) + i*sin(2*pi/8) )
R.<j> = QuadraticField(-1, latex_name='i')

for k in [2..9]:
    Bk = B(k)
    Bk1, Bki, Bku = Bk(1), ZZ(Bk(i)), R(Bk(u))
    info = ' & '.join([latex(val.factor()) if val else str(val) for val in (Bk1, Bki, Bku)])
    print(f"{k} & {info} \\\\\\hline")
```

In a table:

$$
\tiny
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|l|}
  \hline
  k & b_k(1) & b_k(i) & b_k(u)\\\hline
2 & 2^{4} & 2^{2} \cdot 3 & \left(i\right) \cdot (i + 1)^{2} \cdot 3 \\\hline
3 & 2^{8} & 2^{4} \cdot 3^{2} & (i + 1)^{4} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot (4 i + 5) \\\hline
4 & 2^{16} & -1 \cdot 2^{8} \cdot 3^{4} & \left(i\right) \cdot (i + 1)^{8} \cdot 3^{4} \\\hline
5 & 2^{24} & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{6} & \left(-i\right) \cdot (i - 4) \cdot (i + 1)^{12} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot (-8 i + 13) \\\hline
6 & 2^{36} & 2^{18} \cdot 3^{9} & \left(i\right) \cdot (i + 1)^{18} \cdot 3^{9} \\\hline
7 & 2^{48} & 2^{24} \cdot 3^{12} & (i + 1)^{24} \cdot 3^{12} \cdot (440 i + 441) \\\hline
8 & 2^{64} & -1 \cdot 2^{32} \cdot 3^{16} & \left(i\right) \cdot (i + 1)^{32} \cdot 3^{16} \\\hline
9 & 2^{80} & 2^{40} \cdot 3^{20} & (i + 1)^{40} \cdot 3^{20} \cdot (4360 i + 4361) \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: ... wanted to say something more, but also here the 30T characters upper bound does not let me touch some more details. As seen, $b_k(1)$ is two to the power $k^2$ or $k^2\pm 1$. The formula was given in a case by case examination modulo six. Why do we have base twelve instead of two for $i$ instead of $1$? Since this time $(4G)(i)$ instead of $(3G)(1)$ is the infinity point. So computing $d_4(i)$ we obtain zero. And what is $p_4(i)$? It is $12^4$. We have a parallel periodic scheme. And what about $u$? The denominators $d_k(u)$ do not vanish. And $b_k(u)$ has to do with factors $N+1+Ni$.

Comment: For instance, for $k=5$ the corresponding factor is $(i-4)(-8i+13)=45i-44$. The powers of $(i+1)$ and $3$ have a more or less clear pattern. What about the remained factors? For $k=11$ there is the factor $43164 i + 43165$ of $b_{11}(u)$. And for $k=13$ the factor is $427284i + 427285$. For $k=15$ we have $b_k(u)=(i + 1)^{112} \cdot 3^{56} \cdot (4229680i + 4229681)$. And this pattern repeats.