# General solution of the quartic $a^4+b^4=c^4+d^4$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The background to the question:

$$a^4+b^4=c^4+d^4 \label{1}\tag 1 $$

Tito Piezas, Tomita & others have recently given some parametric solutions on Math stack exchange & Math overflow. In math literature there are parametric solutions given in Dickson’s book (vol 2), which includes solutions by Euler & others. Solutions are shown by Zajta (In a AMS journal paper). For degree two we have general solution for $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2.$ For degree three $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$ two general solution has been given. One by Noam Elkies & second by Ajai Choudhry. Even though this problem of the quartic equation (# \ref{1} above) has been around since the time of Euler (for over 200) years a general solution has been evasive. Eight relevant Links are shown below:

- Noam Elkies " [Complete cubic parametrization of the Fermat cubic surface](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/4cubes.html) ".
- Tito Piezas III " [On Euler's elliptic curve for $A^4+B^4 = C^4+D^4$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455960) ".
- Tito Piezas III " [Finding rational points on the elliptic curve for $A^4+B^4 = C^4+D^4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779869) ".
- emacs drives me nuts "[Finding formula that solves $w^4+x^4=y^4+z^4$ over the integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255315)"
- Edward Brisse "[Identities Of Equal Sums Of Like Power](http://euler.free.fr/identities.htm)"
- Wolfram MathWorld "[Diophantine Equation 4th Powers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers)"
- Aurel J. Zajta "[Solutions of the Diophantine equation $A^4+B^4 = C^4+D^4$](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-41-164)", Mathematics of Computation 41, 635-659 (1983),
  [MR717709](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=717709), [Zbl 0525.10011](https://zbmath.org/0525.10011)
- [Jarosław Wróblewski's home page](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Ejwr).
- Ajai Choudhry, "[On equal sums of cubes](https://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181071714)" (English),
  Rocky Mountain Journal of Mathematics 28, No. 4, 1251-1257 (1998), [MR1681666](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1681666), [Zbl 0934.11011](https://zbmath.org/0934.11011), also found in the [Author's publication lists, item #14](https://sites.google.com/view/ajaichoudhry/publications).

Remark:

There are more than a couple of dozen parametric solutions available for equation \eqref{1}. There is a possibility that one of them could be a general solution or maybe not. There are two options. First is, someone needs to write an algorithm to see if the (1420 different) numerical solutions (link as shown above & given at Jaroslaw Wrobelewski website -uni.wroc) are satisfied by one of the published parametric solution. The other option is that someone needs to give a general solution along with a proof.  Any response to the above will be appreciated.

Comment: This degree 4 equation defines a K3 surface, which is not unirational (in contrast to the degree 3 case, where it is unirational). Basically by definition of "unirational," this means there's not a nice formula for the general solution of the type you are probably imagining.

Comment: @sdr, I think you should make your comment an answer, perhaps with some further details! :)

Comment: "To add to Silverman's remark: In the case (x1)^d+(x2)^d=(x3)^d+(x4)^d, with d≥5, depending on one's viewpoint a "formal for a general solution" should indeed exist"

Comment: @Daniel Longhran, Portion of your previous comment is pasted here [ "To add to Silverman's remark: In the case, (x1)^d+(x2)^d=(x3)^d+(x4)^d, with d≥5, depending on one's viewpoint a "formal for a general solution" should indeed exist" ]. So what is view on exponent (d=4). With hindsight from the comments of Naom Elkies & Joe Silverman I think viewers would appreciate if they see a (part two) of your answer.

Comment: @David: I dont understand what you are asking. Can you please be more precise? If you have a separate question it may be good to ask a new one

Comment: @Daniel Loughran. Thanks for answering the question. I know my question has been up for some ten long days. I've put up a bounty so hopefully if there are more answer's I will get an option to select one. Right now, yours is the only single answer. Also, I appreciate the time & effort others have put into giving their comments.

Answer (score 17):

This question has a false premise; there is no such thing as a "formula for a general solution" in this case, exactly for the reason that user sdr describes.

I interpret the question as follows. The OP is looking for polynomials $f_1(x_0,\dots,x_n), \dots, f_4(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ such that any solution to the equation can be written as
$$a = f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n), \dots, d = f_4(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$
for some choice of $x_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. Such a formula exactly corresponds to a rational map of varieties
$$\mathbb{A}^n \dashrightarrow S$$
over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $S$ denotes the corresponding surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$. However there is no such map even over $\mathbb{C}$. This is because $S$ defines a K3 surface and K3 surfaces are not unirational.

This is all explained on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface) for K3 surfaces (here it is explained that they are not uniruled, which implies they are not unirational).

Comment: (Corrected following @Joe Silverman's observtions...) Exactly. This is a fancier version of a point that Joe Lipman made to me many years ago, that there are no (non-constant) rational-function solutions to Fermat equations $x^n+y^n=1$ for $n>2$, because those curves are not genus zero. It was dumbfounding to me at the time! :) That is, in the face of extensive computations I'd done (oof), "it is obvious". :) That is, maybe concepts are worth something!?! :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Right. And moving in the opposite direction (dimension-wise), an analogous statement holds for $$x_1^n+x_2^n+\cdots+x_d^n=1$$ whenever $n\ge d+1$. This is because the canonical divisor of this smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb P^d$ is $\mathcal O(n-d-1)$, so its anti-canonical divisor $\mathcal O(d+1-n)$ is not ample if $n\ge d+1$; but the anti-canonical divisor of a rational variety is ample. As you say, hooray for general theory!

Comment: @JoeSilverman, whoa! Very good! :)

Comment: @JoeSilverman, perhaps you could convert your interesting comment into an answer, so that it doesn't get lost ... ? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett I'm usually hesitant about posting an MO "answer" that doesn't actually answer the question. So I tend to think that generalizations of this sort belong in the comments section.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Ah, well...

Comment: @JoeSilverman Your comment *does* answer the question, because the question concerns the special case $(n,d) = (4,3)$ (once we work over a field in which $-1$ is a 4th power).

Comment: To add to Silverman's remark: In the case $x_0^d + x_1^d = x_2^d + x_3^d$ with $d \geq 5$, depending on one's viewpoint a "formal for a general solution" should indeed exist. This is because the Bombieri-Lang conjecture predicts that all but finitely many rational points lie on finitely many rational and elliptic curves. So it just suffices to list these curves with their rational points and the rational points not on the curves. However there is no hope of proving anything like this at all with current tools!

Comment: Richard guy in his book 'Unsolved Problems' on pages 212 & 213 has this to say. Quote, [ "Euler knew that (133^4 + 134^4 = 59^4 + 158^4). A method is known for generating parametric solutions of (a^4 + b^4 = c^4 + d^4) which will generate all published solutions from the trivial one (x, 1,x, 1); it will only produce solutions of degree (6n + 1). " ] End of quote. Guy's statement can be interpreted as, that since a complete solution is possible for (6n+1) degree, than maybe down the road there could be other solutions for degree's other than degree (6n+1).